# Is it possible to do a DNS Zone Transfer to Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, dns-zone

Is it possible to do a DNS Zone Transfer to Google Cloud DNS on Google Cloud Platform?

I can see references to Zone Transfers in the documentation (eg. https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/) and elsewhere on the web, but cannot find any further information on it.

If it is possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that AFXR/IFXR zone transfers are not supported on the Google Cloud Platform, at least currently at the time of posting.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123907/140872

The best way is to import in BIND format, as explained in [Armando Cuevas's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989856/50948).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** You will need to **EXPORT** your current zone using a third party service or the tools provider by your service provider in BIND or YAML format and then **IMPORT** the zone to Google Cloud DNS.

On (https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating) you can find the detailed instructions on how to perform this procedure.

The export process heavily depends on your service provider. For example, if you are using GoDady you need to follow the instructions on (https://www.godaddy.com/help/export-my-domains-zone-file-records-4166).

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: why not? Can you explain yourself?

Comment: Yes thanks, this is what I have been doing, but I thought AFXR Zone Transfers may be possible, as the term 'zone transfers' is mentioned several times in the documentation.